# because in a sentences with a verb

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I would like to understand the correct way to explain the reason for something using *because*.

For example,

1. Maximum likelihood is a commonly used method in the statistic. That *because* it is easy in comparison with other methods.

   2. Maximum likelihood is a commonly used method in the statistic. That is *because* it is easy in comparison with other methods.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjunction *[because](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/because)* has nothing to do with verbs.  It's purpose is to introduce a clause that justifies or explains an [assertion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assertion).

"Because" can be used in many ways, but a simple form is...

`[Complete sentence A] BECAUSE [complete sentence B]`

- Complete sentence A makes a claim or an assertion.
- Complete sentence B justifies or explains complete sentence A.
- A "complete sentence" is a sentence with both a [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) and a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)#Predicates_in_traditional_grammar).

Here is an example a native speaker may use:

> The [Maximum Likelihood](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html) method is commonly used in statistics because it is easier to use than other methods.

`Complete sentence A:` "The Maximum Likelihood method is commonly used in statistics."

`Assertion:` The method is commonly used.

`Complete sentence B:` "It is easier to use than other methods."